# Is Null return ""

Tags: vba

I have the following code however if the RefDate is blank it is returning #Type!. Can I add in a line to say ifNull = ""

```
Public Function Status(ByVal RefDate As Date) As String

    Dim Description As String

    Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate)
        Case > 60
            Description = "In date"
        Case > 0
            Description = "Expiring"
        Case Else
            Description = "Expired"
    End Select

    Status = Description

End Function
```

If Null return "" nothing or blank

Comment: A `Date` cannot be `Null`. If you have null values, your function must accept a `Variant` instead of `Date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I've changed the input data type also

```
Public Function Status(ByVal RefDate As Variant) As String

    Dim Description As String

    If Len(RefDate) > 0 and IsDate(RefDate) Then

        Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate)
            Case Is > 60
                Status = "In date"
            Case Is > 0
                Status = "Expiring"
            Case Else
                Status = "Expired"
        End Select

    Else

        Status = "No date"

    End If


End Function
```

Comment: `IsNull` and `IsEmpty` are probably a better fit than `Len`.

Comment: @Nathan_sav  so this works for all fields with no date. I am getting "No Date", however fields with dates now return #Error

Comment: Can you post how you are calling it please? `status("01/01/2018")` and `status(date-7)` return "Expired" for me

Comment: @CalumGraham That means you do not in fact have dates. [Make them dates](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365) first.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav nevermind I made a mistake this works. Thanks a lot this websites amazing for people like me!

Comment: Sound.  Mark it as answered then.  Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Trying a similar approach, when comparing with @Ryan Wildry, but now explicitly setting "" to Description

```
Public Function Status(ByVal RefDate As Date) As String

    Dim Description As String

    If CInt(RefDate) = 0 Then 
        Description = ""
    Else
        Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate)
            Case Is > 60
                Description = "In date"
            Case Is > 0
                Description = "Expiring"
            Case Else
                Description = "Expired"
        End Select
    End If

    Status = Description

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Lodi, thanks really appreciat the help. This now returns #Error